# Magento 2: How to set default items for dynamicRows component

Tags: magento2

I have a good question ;)

We have ui form component "dynamicRows". How to set dynamicaly default values? (without grid template)

On example "Custom Options" where we have custom listing but in our case we havn't external collection and use product attribute to save data by json or serialize methods, needs to get on some step data, convert, and apply to dynamicRows. I tried to do that with providers and ko binds but did not work out. Maybe somebody knows how to do this?

Comment: found solution, will update soon